# Can we call api asynchronously in didSelectRow at indexpath in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa, tableview

I want to call api from didSelectRowat indexpath using some id and according to response from api, I need to move to different screen.

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
let contactDB : FMDatabase!
contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath!)
if contactDB != nil{

            if contactDB.open(){

                let read:Int = 1

               let campaignID = self.notification_details[indexPath.row].userId

                let querySQL = "UPDATE new_notifications SET read = \(read) WHERE from_id = \"\(campaignID)\""

                let results:FMResultSet? = contactDB.executeQuery(querySQL,withArgumentsIn: nil)
          }

        contactDB.close()

       }
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
   cell?.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    if  self.notification_details[indexPath.row].notification_type == "LIVE"{
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("live_notification_notificationtab"), object:  self.notification_details[indexPath.row].campaign_id)

    }
```

}

Comment: use tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath), if you want more help show your work

Comment: Yes you can do that, using dispatch.async

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can. But you will either need to prevent user interaction while the asynchronous call is in progress or you will need to break the asynchronous call on user interaction.

To prevent user interaction it is easiest to add another view over the whole table view, add some activity indicator on it and make it hidden as default. Then assuming something like this:

```
func userSelectedItem(_ item: MyObject) {
    progressBackground?.isHidden = false
    progressActivityIndicator?.startAnimating()
    MyObject.fetchDetails(id: item.id) { detailedObject in
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DetailedObjectViewController(detailedObject), animated: true)
        self.progressBackground?.isHidden = true
        self.progressActivityIndicator?.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

This would be called similar to:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    userSelectedItem(items[indexPath.row])    
}
```

but it all depends on how you implemented your table view.

Anyway you might need to break the operation on some events. For instance if user navigates to another screen while the asynchronous operation is in progress you would want to prevent the call after the fetch is done. The most straight forward procedure is to use some variable like `var isVisible: Bool = false` which is then set to `true` on view did appear and set to `false` on view will disappear. You can then use this property inside the block where you push a new view controller and decide to navigate or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely do but, Let's analyze what is the best way to do it.
Let's suppose you have some information rendered in your table view. One user selects a row you want to hit an API, but API response takes time to travel from the server to your device so in this meantime what the user will do? If you allow the user to interact with the UI s/he can scroll through the screen and can select some other rows, hence it's not a good idea to allow the user to interact with the API instead user should be blocked from using the app until you get the response, so the correct thing is to block the user using some loader or indicator and then making the async call.